# Ask fluentd syslog aggregator

Tags: syslog, fluentd, graylog

I have setup a fluentd node to receive any syslog message and sending it to graylog.

But currently Graylog is not receive all logs that previously receive by fluentd. If i check on td-agent.log fluentd is already receive logs but seems not all sent to graylog.

Here is my td-agent.conf configuration

```
<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5140
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag system
</source>
<match system**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type gelf
    host 10.150.2.21
    port 5140
    flush_interval 5s
  </store>
  <store>
     @type stdout
  </store>

</match>
```

Is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check graylog server log in `/var/log/graylog-server/server.log` for errors, maybe there is problem with type of fields (mixed type: num, string that ES can't store). If so, try to create custom index mapping in EL for affected fields.

https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.3/pages/configuration/elasticsearch.html#custom-index-mappings